# Algorithm to generate column prefix patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns, database-design

I am wondering in how to develop a dynamic way to generate column prefix patterns. The main idea is to standardize corporation patterns while defining column names. For example:

- If I have to create a column that is a date, so the prefix will be DT_*column_name*;
- If it is a name column, so it will be NM_*column_name*;
- But if you don't have a well defined pattern, you can suggest a name that need to be approved.

Has anyone ever thought about something like this?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT****

Sorry, I think I didn't explained it enough. It's not exactly for handling type prefixes, but specific business/corporation names. For example (again):

- Column customer should be prefixed with CSTM_
- Column digit should be prefixed with DIGT_
- Column franchising should be prefixed with FRCH_

Comment: Consider how hard/easy it will be, with the tools you have available, to change a column type from, say, `int` to `bigint`, and the corresponding column name change to keep the prefix correct, after that column name has already been used in many places.

Comment: I agree with @hatchet, don't tie column names to column datatypes. With the tools we have today, it's easy to see what the datatype of a column is -- just look at the datatype. This is why you don't see [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) used much anymore.

Comment: It is generally bad practice to put the data type in the name.  This is redundant metadata, and can lead to confusion or mismatched meta data over the life of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Dont think is a good idea.
Consider your organization use different DBs like oracle and mysql with different data types.
The column name should be use to describe the column. You alredy have a type of the column defined.
Another drawback is if you want your application to be supported by multipe database engines. Are you going to change the schema ?